# HashMap have the key though its containsKey method returns false?

Tags: java, android

Here is the log of my map entries. That have two same key exists. How this is possible?

```
 Map<String, Objects> map = new HashMap<String, Objects>();

 addContact("+917111111111");
 addContact("+919222222222");
 addContact("+919222222222");

 private void addContact(String number){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(number))return;

        number = number.trim();
        number = number.replaceAll("-", "");
        number = number.replaceAll(" ", "");

        if(!map.containsKey(number)) {
            map.put(number, null);
        }
    }
    /* While debugging in android studio. I have found the map have below entry.
        0 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@3798} "+919222222222" -> "null"
        1 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@3832} "‪+919222222222" -> "null"
        2 = {HashMap$HashMapEntry@3694} "+917111111111" -> "null"
    */
    map.containsKey("+919222222222");// ==> return false
```

Why this is happen ?

Actual task:

```
private void getContacts(){
    try {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            String strOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";
            cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, strOrder);
            int contactIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID);
            int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
            int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            int photoIdIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do {
                String idContact = cursor.getString(contactIdIdx);
                String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
                String phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);
                //...
                phoneNumber = getFormatedNumber(phoneNumber);

                //as map key same phone number can not be two times
                if(!map.containsKey(phoneNumber)) {
                    map.put(phoneNumber, null);
                    sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phoneNumber + "\nUser Name:--- "
                            + name);
                    sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
                }
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
        textView.setText(sb); //As in output it shows one number showing two times
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

 private String getFormatedNumber(String number){
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(number))return null;

        number = number.trim();
        number = number.replaceAll("-", "");
        number = number.replaceAll(" ", "");

        return number;
    }
```

Comment: could you show more code including map population and logging?

Comment: is it a key exactly?

Comment: How do you have two entries with the same key?

Comment: @Sergey Pauk : Please see my edited question for detail.

Comment: @ Andrew Tobilko : Key is silently different that is contact number

Comment: Such behaviour is not possible with `java.util.HashMap` and `java.lang.String`. Are you sure that this is what you are using? You mentioned android...

Comment: "Silently different"? Is this real code or are your actual keys of a class other than `String`? If so, show the real code and the real class of the keys. If not, then the only reason why there should be such `String` keys is hidden characters, and then of course the keys you see may be different than the one you test.

Comment: `{+917111111111=null, +919222222222=null}`
`true` I have got such results.

Comment: I dunno how you are using this code, but I threw your code into a quick class and at the end, map contains `{+917111111111=null, +919222222222=null}` and containsKey returns `true`.

Comment: maybe you have done something with string default hashcode() function.

Comment: @thinh.lam `java.lang.String` is final class, you cannot modify it and it's `hashCode()` function is working correctly. Also, you cannot instantiate your own class like this `"hello"`. The only explanation would be different JDK which raises the question about Android and what these classes really are.

Comment: I have found one thing may issue is causing only for that I have copied text from debugging and defined as final variable of string then I found string containing the unicode character. That is not visible in notepad.
final String NUM = "\u202A\u202A+91922222222\u202A\u202C";

Can you please help me to remove that type of unicode ? These strings come from while fetching contact number from android default contact provider.

Comment: That 202A is a Left-To-Right Unicode charachter, which even might swap the visible sequence of characters! This can be a prank. Or be in an Arabic/Hebrew context.

Comment: @Joop : This is not a prank !! Actually I am doing one task please see my edited question and get issue like same number printed two times.

Comment: No, no, I meant the data submitted containing `\u202A` - it is invisible, it turns 2'3 into 3'2. In fact it already has been used to make an email attachment .exe look like .png. BTW `map` is a local variable, of the function not returned, but that probably is because of .editing here.

Answer (score 0):

After all discussion, I found the issue like the problem occur due to unicode character append in my string that is invisible while debugging but if we copied into notepad then it clearly visible. as like :
'\u202A\u202A+91922222222\u202A\u202C'